# i master the theme in laravel but when i called it other blade i get an error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a6sW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63uiG.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N287f.png)

i mastering the template and called frontend controller to return category in header.blade.php and its include in dashboard(homepage) and userdashboard file it work on dashboard but not in userdashboard

```
function index(){
 $category = Category::all();
 $featureproduct = Product::where('featured','Featured')->get();
 return view('dashboard',compact('category','featureproduct'));
}
```

`Route::get('/',[FrontendController::class,'index']);`
`Route::middleware('auth','role:user')->group(function(){ Route::get('/dashboard',[UserController::class,'index'])->name('userdashboard'); });`

how can i return data that i can use all differnt blade i have in my project like example

i master navbar and i return the value of category there and now i need to use that navbar in home page , product page etc

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers If you want to make data available to a view every time it is rendered, you use a View Composer. Check the documentation and see if you can implement that.

Comment: Mikola's now-deleted answer had some notes too; variable name should be `$categories`, not `$category`, since `::all()` returns a Collection of Multiple `Category` instances, and your `index()` function should be `public function index()` (converted to a Comment as they do not have enough reputation to do so yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it in the boot method of a serivce provider, such as:

```
namespace App\Providers;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot() 
    {
       $category = Category::all();
       View::share('category', $category);
    }
}
```

For the better performance, you can consider cache categories and then retrieve them from cache

Comment: thanks for ur help. its really help me i add it to the service provider and now its work